# What are 'module' and 'define' in JQuery source code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to read and understand the source code of jQuery. But I can't find any information about the below part. I tried to understand the comments beside it, but can't get any helpful meaning from it.

```
if ( typeof module === "object" && module && typeof module.exports === "object" ) {
    // Expose jQuery as module.exports in loaders that implement the Node
    // module pattern (including browserify). Do not create the global, since
    // the user will be storing it themselves locally, and globals are frowned
    // upon in the Node module world.
    module.exports = jQuery;
} else {
    // Otherwise expose jQuery to the global object as usual
    window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;

    // Register as a named AMD module, since jQuery can be concatenated with other
    // files that may use define, but not via a proper concatenation script that
    // understands anonymous AMD modules. A named AMD is safest and most robust
    // way to register. Lowercase jquery is used because AMD module names are
    // derived from file names, and jQuery is normally delivered in a lowercase
    // file name. Do this after creating the global so that if an AMD module wants
    // to call noConflict to hide this version of jQuery, it will work.
    if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {
        define( "jquery", [], function () { return jQuery; } );
    }
```

I also debugged the code and found that both `module` and `define` are `undefined`.

I wondered where does the `module` and `define` come from? How can I understand it? What is it used for?

Comment: Its hard to tell about the purpose of a two variables in a part of a library file. You can put a break point there and view the code flow stack to figure out its purpose and usage.

Comment: As I said in the question. I have already tried to debug and watch these two variable.  They are all shown as `undefined` in the running time. Thanks.

Comment: Search for UMD (universal module definition). Its docs will explain all the methods used here

Comment: you won't find them in a browser (unless require.js is in use) - they're for environments like node.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This part is a [UMD wrapper](https://github.com/umdjs/umd).

**UMD wrapper?**

It is meant to support the different methods that are used to import or load libraries.
To do so, it is checking if one of the supported module system is available.

In summary, `jQuery` is checking here how it should define itself before doing so.
This way, it supports global insertion as well as the two most common module patterns ([commonJS](http://www.commonjs.org) and [AMD](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/blob/master/AMD.md)).

**Module pattern?**

ES5 and prior did not officially support modules like most languages do (e.g. `import my.module` in java). As a result, by default it is hard to split your code into different modules or files to keep it well organised.

By default, The only way to import modules is to use the `script` tag in the HTML and rely on the global context (i.e. `window`) to link them.
It does not check module's dependencies and you have to manually add each source files you depend on (and make sure that the dependencies of a file are inserted *before* it).

To solve this issue, there is currently 3 main strategies that have been developed so that you can define a module, what it depends on, and what it exports.
It allows to automate module and dependencies import:

1. The [commonJS](http://www.commonjs.org) pattern that is originally [node](https://nodejs.org/en/)'s module pattern though it is now also very used with web applications through builders like [browserify](http://browserify.org) or [webpack](http://webpack.github.io). This is the pattern that is using `module.exports` to define a module (the module is then requested by its consumer with `var module = require('modulePath');`).
2. The [AMD (Asynchronous Module Definition)](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/blob/master/AMD.md) module pattern that is the pattern used by [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org) for example. This is the pattern that is using `define` (`define` is used both to request dependencies and define a new module).
3. And finally, more recently, the [ES6 import pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/import) that will be the way to import modules with next JavaScript's version (actually there is amazing tools such as [babel](https://babeljs.io) that allows you to already use it). It is not supported in the snippet here (but most ES6 module builders also support the two above-mentioned).

Comment: +1 for informative answer. The compressed version of the jquery.js is about 90kb. Is it necessary to apply the AMD module ? In my understanding. AMD pattern is used to load the required module when necessary. So It doesn't need to load all the modules in the beginning. Thanks.

Comment: No the whole point of the UMD wrapper is that the consumer of the library can import it using whatever pattern he is using. jQuery can thus be imported globally, using commonjs or using AMD (and hopefully, one day, using ES6 import). If you are concerned about the utility of the UMD wrapper while building your own library, I would say that it is very very small. This is not the part that will have an impact on your library's size while it makes it available using whatever technique your user is using.

Comment: And yes, using commonjs or umd, the dependencies of an imported module will be automatically imported. You don't need to add them manually. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

`define` (and `define.amd`) is [a RequireJS thing](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html). I'm not sure about `module` but that's possibly related to Node.js (loosely guessing from the comments). This part of the code basically checks to see whether jQuery has been loaded alongside those other libraries, and if so it appears to ensure they are included correctly.

I imagine this is to get around issues where users have had issues with jQuery working alongside those libraries in the past, and this is jQuery's own workaround.

Comment: +1 For the fast answer. It seems like jquery has different way to load . As I knew . one of them is putting all the widgets code together and load everything in the period of page loading. another is loading the specific widget when necessary , that is what we called AMD. Is that right ? Thanks

Comment: That is not exactly true. jQuery is not checking how to include define or module. These things will be already there if the user is using them. More exactly, jQuery checks how it should define itself

Answer (score 0):

The hint is in the comment: "Expose jQuery as module.exports in loaders that implement the Node module pattern". It refers to Node.js module pattern, see http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/ for more information.