# Understanding the Communication between Modules in jQuery Source Code Structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I am trying to read and understand jquery source at their [github repo](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/src) for learning. (I have beginner to intermediate knowledge in JavaScript and have done some projects.)

I saw codes are written in different .js files as different modules. Also I saw this pattern

`define(["module1", "module2", "module3"], function(module1, module2, module3){ ... })`

Which I learnt [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33254607/understand-jquery-source-code) is called AMD pattern for loading the module and **RequireJS** uses it.

I can also see **RequireJS** inside the folder named **external**

Now *I understand how in our html page we incude script tags one by one in the order we want them to be executed*.

**[The Problem]**

But here every file is .js (no .html). So, what I am failing to understand is who is doing / watching over things like

1. **RequireJS** should be loaded before everything
2. Then **RequireJS** should load and execute a particular .js file
   which is the "entry / main module" for jquery?

I also tried to find the answer in `Gruntfile.js`, but could not find it

Can anyone help please?

[Also it will be helpful if someone can provide any suggestion on which .js file / module I should start with as jquery source has lots of modules, for learning]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look for `main` key in `package.json`. It will be the entry point you are looking for. In this case if you take a look it is `"main": "dist/jquery.js"`

Comment: Incase, you are wondering where is `dist` here is the line from `Readme` which says `The built version of jQuery will be put in the dist/ subdirectory, along with the minified copy and associated map file.` So follow the steps to build the source